# What's wrong with this simple recursive function that finds a node in a tree?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have a typical tree structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 42,
    ...other properties...,
    subs:
      [ ...other objects... ]
  },
  ...other objects...
]
```

It can have any shape and number of nodes.

I wrote a method that should recursively find and return a node from the tree based on its `id`:

```
private getFromTree(id: number): object {

  function f(tree: Array<object>): object {
    for (let n of tree) {
      if (n['id'] == id) return n;
      else if (n['subs'].length > 0) f(n['subs']);
    }
  }

  return f(this.tree);

}
```

But it's not working and I'd like to understand why.

(If I replace `return n;` by `console.log(JSON.stringify(n));` then I can see that it finds the node, but with `return n;` it always returns `undefined`. First I thought it was because I'd been missing a second `return` before `f(n['subs']);` but if I put that there then it will only search a single path in the tree.)

Why is it wrong? Why does it return `undefined` if it finds the node? And how should I rewrite it so it will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a return.  When you recurse, you have to return the result of the recursion, otherwise the return value of the inner call gets lost.

I missed the detail that you have an array of elements that each have subs ... that ... complicates things.  Do you have a guarantee that `id` can *only* appear once?  If yes, this version should do the trick.  If no, how do you know *which* element is the correct one for that id?

```
private getFromTree(id: number): object {

  function f(tree: Array<object>): object {
    for (let n of tree) {
      if (n['id'] == id) return n;
      else if (n['subs'].length > 0) {
        let candidate = f(n['subs']);
        if (candidate != undefined) return candidate;
      }
    }
  }

  return f(this.tree);

}
```

Comment: `id`s are unique, so that won't be a problem. Thank you, your solution does the job well. The only thing left for me to understand why only a `return f(n['subs']);` inside the `else if` would be insufficient. Is it so that without the `candidate != undefined` condition it would stop after having traversed a path that had no match on and return `undefined`? Is this the case to be prevented with that check? ..So the `return` is still there in order that the inner call won't get lost, it has only been made conditional. This is how I interpret. Am I right?

Comment: @tom - Yeah, that's exactly right.  If you had some root element that was a common ancestor of _everything_ you probably wouldn't need the conditional check.  But because your base element is an array of trees (`[{ ... }, { ... }]`) we have to do something to ensure that if we reach the bottom of the first tree and don't find the result we want, we check subsequent trees.  This is depth-first recursion.